# holomorphic functions and Laplace operator

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that if $f,g$ are holomorphic in domain $D$ and doesn't have common zeros in it, then in this domain $∆\ln(|f|+|g|)\ge 0$. Where $∆f=\partial^2_x+\partial^2_y$. Is there any quick way, than just paint it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know something about subharmonic functions:  For constants $a$ and $b$ define $$u_{a,b}(z)=\ln(|af+bg|).$$ Then $u_{a,b}$ is subharmonic, being the log of the modulus of a holomorphic  function (in fact on the set where $af+bg\ne0$ it is *harmonic*, since it's the real part of $\log(af+bg)$.)

And $u=\ln(|f|+|g|)=\sup_{|a|\le 1,|b\le 1}u_{a,b}$, so $u$ is subharmonic; now since $u$ is smooth this says $\Delta u\ge0$.

Comment: I didn't quite understand, why $u_{a,b}(z)$ is subharmonic?

Comment: That's a basic part of "knowing something about subharmonic functions": If $F$ is holomorphic then $\log|F|$ is holomorphic. If $V=\{F\ne0\}$ then $\log|F|=\Re \log F$ is harmonic in $V$; otoh if $F(z)=0$ then $\log|F(z)|=-\infty\le\int_0^{2\pi}\log|F(z+re^{it})|\,dt$. (This is an example  of why it's a good thing that the inequality in the definition is required only for $0<r<\delta(z)$.)